# Are RingCT signatures malleable?

Tags: ringct, malleability

Can a RingCT signature of a transaction be slightly modified to create an equivalent transaction (same inputs, same outputs) with a different transaction id?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The transaction ID is based on the hash of everything in the transaction, and the MLSAGs sign everything in the transaction except the MLSAGs themselves.

Therefore, changing anything in the transaction will change the tx hash and thus the ID.

Comment: In Bitcoin, changing the ECDSA signature (r, s) of someone's transaction to (r, -s) gives an equivalent and valid transaction with a different ID. Is a similar thing possible with MLSAGs?

Comment: @glv ECDSA signatures are known to be malleable, especially in Bitcoin's weird use case. Ring signatures are not known to be malleable in this way, as their underlying structure, although still relying on elliptic curves, is fairly different to ECDSA's.